# What is the history of the word "Sentika"?

Tags: etymology

A relatively recent independent [Tokusatsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokusatsu) series, *[Sentika F8ABA6 Jisariz](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt27696380/)*, has caught my attention, specifically due to the series' title in its original Japanese, "華衛士F8ABA6ジサリス".

A breakdown of the title, for those unfamiliar with the series: *Sentika* refers to the in-universe category of Tokusatsu hero many of the cast belong to; F8ABA6 is the hexadecimal color code the protagonist is associated with, and *Jisariz* is the protagonist's name.

The second and third parts of the title are self-explanatory; the color code is rendered in English characters and Arabic numerals, and the protagonist's name is rendered in katakana and carries no significance other than pronunciation and a reference to jetlag unrelated to my query.

It is the first part of the title, *Sentika*, that has caught my eye: As shown above, this word is rendered in all promotional material and the official title using the kanji "華衛士", and it is this word that forms the basis of my query:

- 華 is easy; it is the kanji for "flower" or "blossom". The Sentika themselves display a minor flower theme in the show, and can symbolically 'trim themselves down' as a means of escaping death, analogous to how a gardener would trim a diseased or damaged blossom off of a flowerbush to preserve its health and aesthetics.
- [衛士](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A1%9B%E5%A3%AB) is where the meat of my query lies: Multiple translation sites I have used list three separate definitions for these kanji, minorly paraphrased from the sites in question:

  1. A gate guard for courthouses and administrative buildings in the Ritsuryo system.
  2. A term used in error for young men pressed into forced labor in the [Ritsuryo](https://www.britannica.com/topic/ritsuryo#:%7E:text=The%20ritsury%C5%8D%20system%20refers%20to,Aristocratic%20government%20at%20its%20peak) system.
  3. Guards stationed at certain shrines in Ise and Nagoya to protect the officials working there.

The first and third definitions are quite logical to me: in the show, Sentika serve as a preventative vanguard force for the government/agency/society they are employed under, analogous to a gate guard stopping intruders before they enter the buildings the guards are protecting.

It is the second definition that intrigues me, and which forms the basis for the actual question of this query: **What is the historical basis behind this definition of the word?** Be as detailed as you can; I have reason to believe that this definition has plot significance to the show, as the protagonist is shown to be treated relatively poorly and held in low regard by other Sentika and the agency he works for (or used to work for) in the series proper.

Comment: The jisho link you provided does not exactly say 'A term used in error for young men pressed into forced labor in' - where did you get that?

Comment: @sundowner - スーパー大辞林 says: 誤って、「仕丁（じちよう）」をいう。 I suppose the OP was referring to this definition which apparently originated from a misuse.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you are over-analyzing this matter. While the position named 衛士 might have had special definitions or implications at certain time points in Japanese history, the word itself merely means "guard". It's not a word that is closely associated with the *ritsuryo* system, at least from the perspective of modern Japanese speakers. The kanji 衛 means "guard(ing)", and the kanji 士 just means "-man/-ian/-ist/-er".

Just as the English term "guard" [can refer to various types of historical army units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_army_units_called_%22guards%22), 衛士 can refer to various types of guards. For example, [this article](https://www.afpbb.com/articles/-/2165342) uses the term 衛士 to introduce a guard of London Tower. The word 衛士 has no connotation of being treated like a slave, either. (Security guards in modern buildings are called 警備員 or ガードマン.)

華衛士 is a coined term in this *tokusatsu* video series, and even for native speakers, it's impossible to infer any meaning beyond "blossom/noble/splendid guardian". (The kanji 華 is a little more profound than just "flower/blossom"; it can signify meanings such as "gorgeous", "splendid" and "noble".)

FWIW, I also don't know where the [creative reading](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/creative-furigana/info) センティカ originated from. It might be related to *sentinel* in English, but it's not something an average Japanese person can intuit.